# Why is my carousel div appearing in the same line as the NavBar and how to stop it?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a basic HTML landing page template with a nav bar as the header and the body contains a carousel that displays  the various icons, my problem is that for some reason the two entities appear together as seen below:

[image]

But I need them to appear in separate lines i.e. the nav bar is the header whereas the carousel is the main body.

The code for this is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/landing.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img th:src="@{/images/logo1.png}" alt="Logo" /></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end " id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">View Applications</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="body">
    <div class="carousel" style="display:block; padding-top:50px;">
        <div class="images">
            <img th:src="@{/images/EV Station Locator.jpeg}" alt="EV Station" />
            <img th:src="@{/images/Green Energy.jpeg}" alt="Energy" />
            <img th:src="@{/images/Smart Parking.jpeg}" alt="Parking" />
            <img th:src="@{/images/Smart Purifications.jpeg}" alt="Purification" />
            <img th:src="@{/images/Waste Management.jpeg}" alt="Waste" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the header and the carousel in their seperate rows.

```
<div class="row"> header content </div>
<div class="row"> carousel content </div>
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add both of the container divs under a parent div like this and give the parent flex direction of column, so they will align vertically, also check more about [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```
<div class="parent" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
    <div class="container-fluid"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```